# Require not finding other directive's controller, receiving error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to include my columnDirectives controller in my addColumn directive to that they can communicate. I am getting this error: `Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$compile/ctreq?p0=columnDirective&p1=addColumn` it is definitely due to "require" because removing that line removes the error. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

```
var layout = angular.module('layout-module', []);

layout.controller( "layoutController", function($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [{
        columns: [
            {size: '1'},
            {size: '2'},
        ]
    }];
});

layout.directive('rowDirective', function () {
    return {
        template:     '<div class="row">'
                    + '<div class="small-11 columns">'
                    + '<div class="row">'
                    + '<div data-ng-repeat="column in row.columns" class="small-{{ column.size }} columns">'
                    + '<input type="text" data-ng-model="column.size" column-directive>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '<div class="small-1 columns"><input type="text" data-ng-model="newColumn" column-directive type_of="add"><button add-column></button></div>'
                    + '</div>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

        }
    }
});

layout.directive('columnDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        },
        // scope: { 
        //  directive_type: '=test'
        // },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {

                var columns = scope.row.columns;

                var column_total_before = 0;
                angular.forEach(columns, function(column) {
                    var column_size = parseInt(column.size);
                    column_total_before = column_total_before + column_size;
                });

                if(attrs.typeOf != "add") {
                //Remove current (prior to edit) value from total
                    column_total_before = column_total_before - ngModel.$modelValue;
                    var default_value = 1;
                } else {
                    if (column_total_before == 12) {
                        var default_value = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        var default_value = (12 - column_total_before);
                    }
                }

                //Convert string to integer
                viewValue = parseInt(viewValue);

                //Add total existing columns with new value
                column_total = column_total_before + viewValue;
                scope.column_total = column_total;

                if(column_total >= 1 && column_total <= 12 && viewValue > 0) {
                    return viewValue;
                } else if (isNaN(viewValue)) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(default_value);   
                    return default_value;
                } else if (column_total_before == 12 && viewValue == 0) {
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(default_value);
                    ngModel.$render();
                    return default_value;
                }

            });
        }
    }
});


layout.directive('addColumn', function() {
    return {
        require: "columnDirective",
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, columnDirective) {
            el.on('click', function() {

            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`columnDirective` is not on the same element as `addColumn`.

If `addColumn` is a child of `columnDirective` write it this way:

```
return {
    require: "^columnDirective",
    ...
```

More information about your problem is in the docs. http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:ctreq

But in your case you might have to consider depending on the `rowDirective`'s scope and using `ng-click`

Comment: thanks, If I appended column-directive to the parent div of input is there anyway to require the input's ngmodelcontroller at the parent div level where column directive is?

Comment: You can only depend a controller which is a parent or a sibling of your directive. Otherwise events and shared services come to your rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `column-directive` is attached to `input` element, which is a sibling to your `button` element.

When you define require as `require: "columnDirective"` than Angular expect the `column-directive` to be found on the same element (`input`).

Since your directives are siblings, the only way to communicate between them is to use a shared service.